# Swiper.js - Linking two slider instances?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slider, swiper.js

I have 2 instances of Slider.js on a product page:

```
var swiperProdImage = new Swiper('.swiper-productimage', { }

var swiperThumbs = new Swiper('.swiper-productthumbs', { }
```

I want first to control second on next/prev swipes but can't get slideNext() to work?

Where am I going wrong here?

```
swiperProdImage.on('slideNextTransitionStart', function() {

   swiperThumbs.slideNext();
   swiperThumbs.update(true);

});

swiperProdImage.on('slidePrevTransitionStart', function() { 

   swiperThumbs.slidePrev();
   swiperThumbs.update(true);

});
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use this to sync your sliders (to do right after initialisation of your sliders) :

```
// Assign each other controls
swiperProdImage.controller.control = swiperThumbs;
swiperThumbs.controller.control = swiperProdImage;
```

Comment: this works when i transition a slide but not when i transition a thumb. Like i swipe my main carousel and the thumbs swipe too, but if i swipe my thumbs the main carousel doesnt change (only changes on click of each thumb)